# What node would I add to these two material setups to change color, and where do I put it?

Tags: materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I'd like to change the colors for these two material setups and don't know what node to add and where to place it -
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). These seem to be mostly image texture-based materials, so you can only 'adjust' the colors. At the top of the *Principled BSDF node* (the large one) is an input called *Base Color*. I'd start there.

Comment: Add Color > Mix node  or  RGB Curve node or Hue/Saturation node on the string to "Base Color" of Principled BSDF (as Jachym suggested)